# How can i pass optional arguments in Django view

Tags: django, view, arguments

I have one function in view like

```
def  calculate(request , b)
```

I want that this function should work even if b is not passes to it

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Default arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

```
def calculate(request, b=3):
```

Answer (score 74):

You may also need to update your URL dispatch to handle the request with, or without, the optional parameter.

```
url(r'^calculate/?(?P<b>\d+)?/?$', 'calculate', name='calculate'),  
url(r'^calculate/$', 'calculate', name='calculate'),
```

If you pass b via the URL it hits the first URL definition. If you do not include the optional parameter it hits the second definition but goes to the same view and uses the default value you provided.

Comment: Can you use both definitions in `reverse('calculate', ...)`?

Comment: Yes, you can provide both args and kwargs as attributes passed to the reverse method.

Comment: Super-correct !
Alternatively, since defining two separate urls is necessary, you might want to specify the default value of the missing parameter in the url itself, to keep all decisions in one place:

`url(r'^calculate/$', 'calculate', {'b': 3}, name='calculate'),`

Answer (score 13):

Passing a default value to the method makes parameter optional.

In your case you can make:

```
def calculate(request, b=None)
    pass
```

Then in your template you can use condition for different behaviour:

```
{% if b %}
    Case A
{% else %}
    Case B
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate(request, b=None)
```